# How to list PDF Files names and path in a SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help on script to list PDF Files names and path in a SQL Server Database.

```
DECLARE @full_path VARCHAR(500) 
SET @full_path = '\some\path\here'

DECLARE @FindFile TABLE 
 (FileNames nvarchar(500)
  ,depth int
  ,isFile int)

INSERT INTO @FindFile 
EXEC xp_DirTree @Path,1,1

SELECT FileNames from @FindFile where isFile=1
```

It didn't work, it only listed file names without the path?

Comment: This has your answer: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1642213/get-full-path-from-sysxpdirtree

Comment: Here you have a good guide to get what you need http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/12/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files-part2.html